# assigning "textbox1.text" as default text on an input box

Tags: string, textbox, default, inputbox

```
Dim result As String = InputBox("title", "The Prompt Text", "default text")
```

How can I make default text be `textbox1.text`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using:

```
Dim pretext As String = textbox1.Text
Dim plaintext As String = InputBox("title", "The Prompt Text", pretext)
```